# Cannot retrieve a column data using Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to access a column of data using Rails 3 but unable to retrieve it.Finally an empty array is coming while rendering the out put table.Please check my table first which is given below.

```
table- Payment_vendors:
id  Receipt_No   type   v_amount    v_date      c_date      v_name    v_status

7    150325006   SWD     60.00     2015-04-15  2015-04-28   Deepak    No

8    150325006   GOODS   1195.00   2015-04-15  2015-04-28   Deepak    No
```

From the above table i want to access "type" column  by using the v_name.I tried once but got the empty array.I explaining my code below.

> payment.html.erb:

```
<div class="tbpaddingdiv2">
    <%= form_for :payment,:url => {:action => "check_type" },remote: true do |f| %>
    <div class="totalaligndiv">
      <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-6 pull-left"><span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Type :</div></span>
      <%= f.select(:s_catagory,options_for_select([['Wood','Woods'],['Puja Samagree','GOODS'],['Sweeper','SWD'],['Photo Grapher','PHOTO'],['Burning Assistant','BURNING'],['BRAHMIN','BRAHMIN']],selected: "Type"),{},{:class => 'form-control',:onchange => ("$('#switch_car').submit()")}) %>
      </div>
      <div id="div_select" style="display:none">
      <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-6 pull-left" ><span class="input-group-addon text-left" ><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Select Vendor :</div></span>
      <div id="name-option">

      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
      <div class="tbpaddingdiv1 text-center">
        <%= f.submit "submit",:class => "btn btn-success",:id => "switch_car" %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

> payments_controller.rb:

```
class PaymentsController < ApplicationController

    def payment
        @payment=Vendor.new
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html 
            format.js
        end

    end
    def check_type  
        if params[:commit]=="submit"
           @vendor_type=PaymentVendor.where(:v_name => params[:payment][:v_name] ).pluck(:type)
        else
            @v_name=Vendor.where(:s_catagory => params[:payment][:s_catagory] ).pluck(:v_name)
        end
    end
end
```

> check_type.js.erb:

```
<% if @v_name %>
$("#div_select").css("display", "block");
$("#name-option").html("<%= escape_javascript (render 'nameoption' ) %>");
$("#name-option").slideDown(350);
<% end %>
<% if @vendor_type  %>
console.log('hello')
$(".flash-message").html('<%= escape_javascript flash[:notice] %>');
$("#paymentdetail").css("display", "block");
$("#paymentoption").html("<%= escape_javascript (render 'paymentdetails' ) %>");
$("#paymentoption").slideDown(350);
<% end %>
```

After getting all column data i need when type=="SWD" ,all related value of this row will display in below table.

> paymentdetails.html.erb:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <colgroup>
        <col class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
        <col class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
        <col class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
        <col class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
        <col class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center"><input type="checkbox"></th>
            <th class="text-center">Sl. No</th>
            <th class="text-center">Date</th>
            <th class="text-center">Receipt No.</th>
            <th class="text-center">Amount</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1-1" name="checkbox1-1"></th>
            <td class="text-center"></td>
            <td class="text-center"></td>
            <td class="text-center"></td>
            <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-rupee"></i></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: What is the exact error you are receiving? See the guidelines on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @screenmutt : Actually I am getting the empty array on template.

Comment: You've included so much information here that isn't relevant. Take the following steps (1) Check your table manually, does it have data? (2) Check the output of your command in the controller, is it an empty array there? (3) Remove all the unrelated code (i.e. the form and the table). Once you have the data being pulled, you can use it anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to pass `params[:payment][:v_name]` instead `params[:v_name]`

Try this: in your controller's `check_type` method:

```
@vendor_type = PaymentVendor.where(:v_name => params[:v_name] ).pluck(:type)
```